# giving the buttons on/off functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 buttons. each button is linked to a function which will display some data on clicking. I am working on a functionality wherein once the button is clicked it should run the function with data & once again if i do second click on the same button it should deselect the button and should return another function where I load default data for the page(another function). I have tried with the below code & its not working please help me getting proper output.

I am looping through all the buttons to check which one is clicked and if it is clicked I am adding class to it, but I am not able to check for second click.

```js
$('.boxCount ').click(function(e){
  var btns = $('.boxCount ');
  for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
    var btnClicked = $(e.currentTarget);
    btnClicked.addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" class="boxCount col-md-2" title="Moving Vehicle">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" class="boxCount col-md-2" title="Moving Vehicle">Button 2</button>
<button id="btn3" class="boxCount col-md-2" title="Moving Vehicle">Button 3</button>
<button id="btn4" class="boxCount col-md-2" title="Moving Vehicle">Button 4</button>
<button id="btn5" class="boxCount col-md-2" title="Moving Vehicle">Button 5</button>
```

I am looking to achieve the button on/off functionality for buttons so that I can run one function on first click(switch on method) and run default function(another function) for 2nd click & this is a (switching off) button.

Comment: You don't need to loop through anything, `$(this)` would give you the clicked element inside the event handler. You can then use something like `.hasClass("active")` in a basic `if` to handle your two states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend Mamun's answer, when I usually have situations where I need on/off functionality on a button I do it like this:

```
    $('.boxCount').click(function(e){
        //add e.preventDefault() here if your button 
        //includes links that you don't want them to go anywhere
        if($(e.currentTarget).hasClass("active")) {
            $(e.currentTarget).removeClass("active")
            //functionality for when you need the button to stay 'off' and do other things in the meantime
        }
        else {
            $(e.currentTarget).addClass("active");
            //for when the button needs to stay on, doing other things in the meantime
        }
        //add return false; here if you have links 
        //that don't go anywhere (this is for older browsers)
    });
```

I do it like this because usually on 'on' I have some things going on there and the same goes for off, so a simple `toggleClass` won't work

Answer (score 2):

You can simply toggle the class on the clicked button  using `toggleClass()` like the following way:

```js
$('.boxCount').click(function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" class="boxCount col-md-2" title="Moving Vehicle">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" class="boxCount col-md-2" title="Moving Vehicle">Button 2</button>
<button id="btn3" class="boxCount col-md-2" title="Moving Vehicle">Button 3</button>
<button id="btn4" class="boxCount col-md-2" title="Moving Vehicle">Button 4</button>
<button id="btn5" class="boxCount col-md-2" title="Moving Vehicle">Button 5</button>
```